# Table id ia referenced HTML a tag with href to next page, I want to sen the text inside that a tag to next page

Tags: javascript, html, spring

I have a table where first column is id which is in a html 'a' tag. I want to send that id value to the page in 'href' field when clicked on that id.

Answer (score 0):

You can assemble a GET request in the url.

```
<a href="nextpage?id=23">23</a>
```

And then fetch the GET parameter on the nextpage